# Building a workflow application

Tags: web-applications, webserver, workflow, workflow-activity

I have been tasked with building a simple web-based workflow application. Its should be able to handle at least 20 user-named steps, with user-defined paths (be they based on user choice or parallel paths). Progress will need to be saved between usage. What framework, language, etc should I be using here? Is there anything simple out there to use?

Comment: Use a workflow engine or don't use a workflow engine.

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: The framework and language depends on what kind of webserver is running. You need to define that first.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Process Maker](http://www.processmaker.com/), it provides you with a GUI, and ability to call web services, run queries, etc.  The company also provides a [free and open-source version](http://www.processmaker.com/community-2).